# Avoid using persitence layer on model for aggregate children

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, persistence, crud

## Problem

Suppose the following DDD model.

```
class Building {
    Room[] rooms

    addRoom(String name)  {
        room = new Room(name) // Model
        db.create(room)       // Persistence!!!
        rooms.add(room)       // Model
    }
}

class Room {
    String name
}
```

We can see that `Building` is the **AR** and is responsible for creating its aggregate `Room`. My problem is when I try to **Create** `Room` in the database following the **CRUD** model. At some moment, one can create a room, so my model will call `Building` and it will create the `Room`. However, my model shouldn't use the persistence layer.

**Note** that you can add rooms, which means that you can have a `Building` in the database inconsistent with the actual model. So I would have to **update** my `Building` too.

If I move the **Creation** of `Room` for the database outside the model, then, when I **update** my `Building` in the database, the `Room` must already exist in the database. But `Room` is an aggregate child of `Building` and shouldn't be accessed by classes other than `Building`.

## Question

> How do I **Create** the `Room` in the database outside the model keeping the `Room` as aggregate child?

Comment: Which programming language? Which version? Add some tags please.

Comment: @DJDaveMark it's for Java

Comment: Here's an example with Spring: https://www.baeldung.com/hexagonal-architecture-ddd-spring

Answer (score 1):

please look up the repository pattern if you use DDD - it should become obvious on how the persistence and db interaction might work.

put simply, the repository is responsible to retrieve and store **aggregates** as a whole.

in your case you would have some `CrudRepository<Building>` which interacts with the db and stores the building, cascading all rooms.

One thing to note here: mere composition between two object types may be not enough to require modelling as an aggregate. If invariants are not existent and transactional consistency is not required, they may as well be two different aggregates referencing each other (via IDs)

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, if I didn't get it wrong, `Building` is the *aggregate root* that holds a collection of `Room` *entities* (remember that aggregate itself is an entity too).

A *repository* that looks something like the following should be responsible for persistence operations (e.g. create, find, update, etc.) of your aggregate root, that is `Building`.

```java
public interface Repositoy<Building> {

    Building findById(String buildingId);

    void store(Building building);
}
```

You have correctly pointed out that domain operations (e.g. add room in your case) must happen through the aggregate root. However, the aggregate root (or any other entity) *must not take up persistence responsibilities* (as you purported: `db.create(room)`).

Client interacts with the domain through a *domain service* or an *application service*. Those, in turn, retrieves an aggregate root through its repository, makes necessary modification, and stores the *entire aggregate* in a single transaction. Consequently, upon each successful transaction, you always have a *consistent aggregate* with its children in database, nothing to worry about missing parent, child, etc.

```java
public class SomeDomainOrApplicationService {

    private Repositoy<Building> repository;

    public void createRoomServiceMethod(String buildingId) {

        // retrieve aggregate root
        Building building = repository.findById(buildingId);

        // modify aggregate
        String roomName; // assign room name
        building.addRoom(roomName);

        // store aggregate
        repository.store(building);
    }
}
```